# Using expect.any() with supertest to check response body

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to use supertest to check res.body with Jest, but the following snippet will always fail

```js
request(app)
  .post('/auth/signup')
  .send(validEmailSample)
  .expect(200, {
    success: true,
    message: 'registration success',
    token: expect.any(String),
    user: expect.any(Object),
  });
```

But when I rewrite the test to check the body in a callback as follows:

```js
test('valid userData + valid email will result in registration sucess(200) with message object.', (done) => {
  request(app)
    .post('/auth/signup')
    .send(validEmailSample)
    .expect(200)
    .end((err, res) => {
      if (err) done(err);
      expect(res.body.success).toEqual(true);
      expect(res.body.message).toEqual('registration successful');
      expect(res.body.token).toEqual(expect.any(String));
      expect(res.body.user).toEqual(expect.any(Object));
      expect.assertions(4);
      done();
    });
});
```

The test will pass.

I'm sure it has something to do with `expect.any()`. As Jest's documentation says that expect.any and expect.anything can only be used together with `expect().toEqual`, and `expect().toHaveBeenCalledWith()`
I'm wondering if there's any better way to do it, to use expect.any in supertest's expect api.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [expect.objectContaining(object)](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject).

> matches any received object that recursively matches the expected properties. That is, the expected object is a subset of the received object. Therefore, it matches a received object which contains properties that are present in the expected object.

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.post("/auth/signup", (req, res) => {
  const data = {
    success: true,
    message: "registration success",
    token: "123",
    user: {},
  };
  res.json(data);
});

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require('./app');
const request = require('supertest');

describe('47865190', () => {
  it('should pass', (done) => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    request(app)
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        expect(res.body).toEqual(
          expect.objectContaining({
            success: true,
            message: 'registration success',
            token: expect.any(String),
            user: expect.any(Object),
          }),
        );
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Integration test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/47865190/app.test.js (12.857s)
  47865190
    ✓ should pass (48ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.js   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.319s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/47865190

Comment: Alternatively, 
`expect(res.body).toMatchObject({ success:true, ...});`

Answer (score 1):

Could assign it to a variable and do whatever you want.

```
const app = require('./app');
const request = require('supertest');

describe('valid userData + valid email will result in registration success(200) with message object.', () => {
  it('should pass', (done) => {
    const res = await request(app).post('/auth/signup');
    expect(res.body).toEqual(
      expect.objectContaining({
        success: true,
        message: 'registration success',
        token: expect.any(String),
        user: expect.any(Object),
      }),
    );
  });
});
```